# 80's sci fi short story/film

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I know this is a bit of a long shot but I have been trying to track down this movie for many years. It was an old movie my brother and I used to watch on vhs as kids. The story was two lads try to produce the perfect girl with a potion they acquired, the keep pouring this potion and different girls appear, some fat and then one has just half a body on a dining table. The only quote I remeber was when they poured it for the final time one said "Not too much, not too little"

Not a lot to go on I know but thought I'd give it a shot.

Answer (score 10):

It's from the TV show [*Amazing Stories*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088478/?ref_=tt_ov_inf), [Season 2 Episode 2, *"Miscalculation"*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511105/), which aired September, 1986.

Fan ReCap from [TV.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/amazing-stories/miscalculation-69858/)

> A college student, Phil, inevitably strikes out when trying to get a
>   date. His fortunes take a turn for the better when he inadvertently
>   discovers a mix of two chemicals that bring any picture to life.
>   Phil goes to his dorm room and tries to animate a model but uses too
>   much of the chemicals - the resulting woman is a giant who wrecks his
>   dorm room trying to get to him. Fortunately, the animation wears off
>   and the model disappears. The second time he uses too little and the
>   model crumples into a skeleton and then dust. The third time he only
>   gets half of the picture and he has an attractive woman at his beck
>   and call...but she only exists from the waist up. Finally he gets it
>   just right...but another student barges in and gets her instead. Phil
>   ends up with the quiet but "real" girl who has been after him all the
>   time.

It has the half-woman-growing-out-of-the-table-scene scene, and the magic goo that the kid pours over pictures to make them turn real for a short time.

Comment: Omg!! Thank you that is it

Comment: @user38957, welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange! Please click to accept the answer, so that the question is marked as answered.